# Can't connect to gunicorn

Tags: docker, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to dockerize my Django website. However, I am stuck on this connection error to gunicorn that occurs after running my start-server.sh file.

If I run `gunicorn mysite.wsgi --preload --bind 127.0.0.1:8010 --workers 3` in my terminal, then everything runs fine, so it is not clear to me why it won't run when I build my docker.  container.

I am very new to docker so if there is more information needed that I have left out, please let me know.

**start-server.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# start-server.sh
if [ -n "$DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME" ] && [ -n "$DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD" ] ; then
    (cd /opt/app/website/; python manage.py createsuperuser --no-input)
fi
echo $PWD
(cd /opt/app/website/; gunicorn mysite.wsgi --preload --bind 127.0.0.1:8010 --workers 3) &
nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

**dockerfile**

```
# Dockerfile

# FROM directive instructing base image to build upon
FROM python:3.7-buster


# Install NGINX
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx vim -y --no-install-recommends
COPY nginx.default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

# Install Source scripts
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/pip_cache
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/website


COPY requirements.txt start-server.sh /opt/app/
COPY website /opt/app/website/
WORKDIR /opt/app/website
RUN pip install -r /opt/app/requirements.txt --cache-dir /opt/app/pip_cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/app

# Build Kinbank database
RUN git clone https://github.com/kinbank/kinbank.git /opt/app/website/kinbank
RUN cd /opt/app/website/kinbank && git pull
RUN python /opt/app/website/add_columnGlottocode.py 
RUN csvs-to-sqlite /opt/app/website/kinbank/kinbank/cldf/*.csv /opt/app/website/kinbank.sqlite3
RUN csvs-to-sqlite  /opt/app/website/kb/static/about.csv /opt/app/website/kinbank.sqlite3
RUN python /opt/app/website/manage.py makemigrations
RUN python /opt/app/website/manage.py migrate

EXPOSE 8010
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
CMD ["/opt/app/start-server.sh"]
```

**output**

```
Attaching to web_1
web_1  | /opt/app/website
web_1  | [2021-06-26 23:05:53 +0100] [9] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
web_1  | [2021-06-26 23:05:53 +0100] [9] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8010)
web_1  | [2021-06-26 23:05:53 +0100] [9] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
web_1  | [2021-06-26 23:05:54 +0100] [9] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8010)
web_1  | [2021-06-26 23:05:54 +0100] [9] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
web_1  | [2021-06-26 23:05:55 +0100] [9] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8010)
web_1  | [2021-06-26 23:05:55 +0100] [9] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
web_1  | [2021-06-26 23:05:56 +0100] [9] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8010)
web_1  | [2021-06-26 23:05:56 +0100] [9] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
web_1  | [2021-06-26 23:05:57 +0100] [9] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8010)
web_1  | [2021-06-26 23:05:57 +0100] [9] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
web_1  | [2021-06-26 23:05:58 +0100] [9] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('127.0.0.1', 8010)
```

Comment: What is using the port? Nginx?

Comment: Ah! So obvious. Thanks!